# (SOLVED) How do I force the catch exception? (or retrieve exception variable)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

How do I force my else-statement to go to the catch exception? I got this code:

```
try
{
    user.UserName = editedUser.Username;
    user.Email = editedUser.Email;
    user.RowVersion = editedUser.RowVersion;

    var result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ListOfUsers");
    }
    else
    {
        Somehow go to Catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) // <---------- How?
    }
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    var exceptionEntry = ex.Entries.Single();
    var clientValues = (ApplicationUser)exceptionEntry.Entity;
    var databaseEntry = exceptionEntry.GetDatabaseValues();

    if (databaseEntry == null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"User{editedUser.ID} was deleted before you applied the changes.");
    }
    else
    {
        var databaseValues = (ApplicationUser)databaseEntry.ToObject();

        if (databaseValues.UserName != clientValues.UserName)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Username", $"Current username in Database: {databaseValues.UserName}");
        }
        if (databaseValues.Email != clientValues.Email)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", $"Current email in Database: {databaseValues.Email}");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user you were trying to edit was modified by someone else. Editing operation was canceled and the current values ​​in the database are now shown below. If you still want to edit this user, click Save again, otherwise click Undo");

        user.RowVersion = databaseValues.RowVersion;
        ModelState.Remove("RowVersion");
    }
}
```

And it's necessary for me to use the **DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex** variable in order to get my database entry values.

If it's possible to get these db entry values in the else-statement instead, how do I go about that?

EDIT - SOLUTION:
Instead of using Try/catch, I found out that we should avoid this and handle errors in code, i.e. if-else. In the else statement, I found the exception that the Identity used, and handled that. And getting the database values, I used:

`var dbUser = await userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == user.Id);`

And by doing this I can compare the properties of both the 'dbUser' and 'user'.

Comment: The catch statement will be invoked if an exception is thrown. So, you could just `throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException();`, but that seems kind of strange. Perhaps you should trace the code and find out why you're not getting `result.Succeeded` if the exception you expect in that case is not being thrown from the call to `UpdateAsync`.

Comment: @RufusL When I do that, my DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex variable is empty and can't retrieve my database entries. And the userManager.UpdateAsync(user); will not throw an exception when it fails, that's why I use if-else

Comment: I don't see what good entering the `catch` statement "manually" is going to do you. I mean, you could just `throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException` but it isn't as if it'll be hydrated, so you won't get any useful information from it. `UserManager.UpdateAsync` returns an instance of `Task<IdentityResult>` and [`IdentityResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityresult) has a collection of `Errors`. Maybe you could use that if `result.Succeeded` is `false`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that - I should have been more clear that I wasn't actually advocating throwing an exception, because that makes no sense. You've stated that it will not throw an exception when it fails, so why do you expect that exception? Does the class not document how to determine the error if the `result` is not `Succeeded`?

Comment: @RufusL Because I'm trying to make an concurrency check, and it will 100% fail if 2 people edit the RowVersion(); simultanously - which is why I want to do something about the database entries in the else-block

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Then how do I get the database entries in that else block? since it's on the exception variable in catch

Comment: If the exception isn't thrown, then you won't get it from an exception. What do you see in the `Errors` collection?

Comment: @RufusL Oh maybe I need to look at the Errors collection, I will look into that and give a notice in here if I got the solution, thanks!

Comment: The `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` will only be thrown if there is a concurrency problem; two users trying to edit the same record simultaneously for example. It won't be thrown on general errors, such as trying to update a username or email to one that already exists. Something like that should be in `result.Errors`. You won't have the `databaseValues`, but you should still know that there is a duplicate name or duplicate email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what are you after, but the approach is completely wrong.

`DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is EF Core specific exception, while identity is abstract framework, so this exception by design should never flow, hence the `catch` will never be hit.

By design, the errors are provided through `IdentityResult.Errors`, and concurrency issues by default are provided with `IdenitityError.Code` equal to "ConcurrencyFailure", which can be seen in EF Core [store implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L192):

> ```cs
> try
> {
>    await SaveChanges(cancellationToken);
> }
> catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
> {
>    return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.ConcurrencyFailure());
> }
> ```

So you need to restructure the code. Remove the whole `catch` block, and in `else` clause, check for concurrency error, and if so, use `UserManager.FindByIdAsync` to get the current (database) data and perform your logic.

Something like this:

```cs
else
{
    var concurrencyError = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault(error =>
        error.Code == nameof(IdentityErrorDescriber.ConcurrencyFailure));
    if (concurrencyError != null)
    {
        var dbUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.Id);
        // Check for null(deleted) or modified properties here
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, but the problem now is that it doesn't actually check the database entries. I used your logic and it shows assignment values i did to my 'user(on line 3 of my code in this post)' but not my database. I believe the await userManager.FindByIdAsync thinks the assignment is the current data in the database.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that `Update` has attached the passed entity, so `Find` is just returning it. So you need different method, may be directly querying `userManager.Users`, eventually combined with `AsNoTracking()` to query the database values.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, this one worked, and showed the Database entry value: var dbUser = await userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == user.Id); And with this and user I can compare them and do stuff!